# How to get all folders with name in skydrive gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, onedrive

I am using skydrive gem in my rails application . If there any function wherein I can find with all the folder names like in rails we have find_all_by.

I am following http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/skydrive/1.2.0/Skydrive link

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to by an implementation of a search / find method in the gem directly. But I believe you could add it yourself into it through the GET request with search parameter of the REST API of OneDrive (former SkyDrive)  https://dev.onedrive.com/items/search.htm.

Comment: I am able to get my search string in parameters . Now I am not getting how to use the OneDrive search API